# How to think about how much distance is covered in this problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

The exercise reads roughly like this:

> We shoot an arrow in a straight line against an opposing wall. The arrow travels with an average velocity of 80m/s - we hear the impact after 1 second and can assume sound travels on average with 320m/s. What's the min. amount of distance the arrow covered?

Simple problem, but it still got me. I did a brief estimation like that:

If the arrow would fly 1 sec, it covers 80m and the sound would take 0.25 sec to return. That would be a total time of 1.25 sec. If the arrow flies 0.5 sec, it covers 40m and the sound would take 0.125 sec to return. That would be a total time of 0.625 sec. So in the one second the arrow should travel more than 40 meters but less than 80. That was enough to answer the multiple choice question, but my question is: is there a proper term for calculating this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let the distance to the wall in metres be $d$.

Then using distance = speed $\times$ time, the time in seconds taken for the arrow to reach the wall is $\cfrac d{80}$ and the time taken for the sound to return is $\cfrac d{320}$. The total time taken before you hear the sound is therefore $$1=\frac d{80}+\frac d{320}$$and this is an equation you can solve for $d$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you!